# Javascript executing backwards

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

An app is using **Cordova** with **InAppBrowser** plugin version 3.2.1 to load a webpage built in Asp.Net 4.5.2. We have been experiencing erratic behaviour, so I've made a page to catch the problem and share it here.

This page contains a really simple button executing JS within the [onclick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp):

```html
<button onclick="alert('1'); alert('2'); alert('3');"> EXECUTION</button>
```

It works perfectly, but when the website is embed in the app, the execution order runs backwards, displaying:

- Alert 3
- Alert 2
- Alert 1

Using unobstrusive JS with the same results:

```html
<button id="testButton">Test</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testButton").click(function () {
       alert('1');
       alert('2');
       alert('3');
    });
});
```

Running the website in ios with Safari works perfectly fine.

Any idea?

### Update

As suggested by @Bergi in the comments, adding a sleep `timeout` verifies a problem managing synchronous calls. Following code triggers the alerts in the right order:

```js
$("#testButton").click(function () {
    alert('1');
    setTimeout(function () { alert('2'); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ alert('3'); }, 4000);
});
```

But not when the timeouts are closer. The following displays the alerts in wrong order:

```js
$("#testButton").click(function () {
    alert('1');
    setTimeout(function () { alert('2'); }, 1);
    setTimeout(function(){ alert('3'); }, 2);
});
```

### Update 2

As proposed by @Bergi in the comments, I've tried:

```
$("#testButton").click(function () {
    var x = []; x.push(1); x.push(2); alert(x);
});
```

With a correct result, displaying an alert containing: "1,2".

[Issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/750) has been reported.

Comment: I'd guess their embedding doesn't provide a proper synchronous version of `alert`, rendering them all at once (on top of each other). You might verify this by trying to add some `sleep()` calls in between.

Comment: "*Any idea?"* - don't use `alert()` :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi for the ideas. The use of `alert()` is just to simplify the code and share it here. Of course that is not our code in production ;)

Comment: @MarioLevrero Like @Bergi said, you can `sleep()` or just `console.log()` to verify. :)

Comment: Thanks, Bergi and @Muhammad. I've added a sleep using Timeout and now the order is correct.

Comment: @MarioLevrero Are you saying that *actual* code runs backwards (so this is not an artifact of how alerts are showing)? Please provide that code as well

Comment: @MarioLevrero Like what happens when you do `var x = []; x.push(1); x.push(2); alert(x)` - does it throw an exception? Or alert `2,1`? Or does it work as expected?

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi I've tried with that code (Update 2 in the Q). The execution there is correct.

Comment: The first comment from @Bergi sounds like the answer. Instead of timeouts, you could easily confirm this with some kind of logging or breakpoint in between each `alert()` call. Does this browser support either `console.log` or `debugger` statements? If not, you could put `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` calls in between to fetch some nonexistent resource on your server, e.g. `fetch("log-one")`, `fetch("log-two")`. The fetches will fail with 404 errors, but you can check the server log to see the order they arrived. I'll bet they all arrive in a row before you click on any of the alerts.

Comment: Another possible way to check @Bergi's theory: are the alert boxes draggable? You could move the top one and see if another one shows up behind where it was.

Comment: Or, do the alert boxes automatically size themselves to fit the content? You could put a really long message in the first one, a shorter message in the second, and even shorter in the third. You may get to see all three of them this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bergi suggests in a comment, the version of `alert()` you're calling is likely to be asynchronous on some platforms and synchronous on others. This would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Instead of using `window.alert()` at all, when you need an alert box you should probably use `navigator.notification.alert()` from [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html).

Note the signature for this function:

```
navigator.notification.alert( message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName] )
```

The `alertCallback` function gets called after the alert box is dismissed. Even if some implementations are synchronous (because they use the native browser `alert()` function) and some are asynchronous, `navigator.notification.alert()` provides a compatible interface for both cases.

Well, mostly compatible. On platforms where `navigator.notification.alert()` calls the native `alert()`, the function will not return until the alert box is dismissed by the user. On platforms that use some other implementation, the function may return immediately. But in both cases, `alertCallback` will be called when the alert box is dismissed.

cordova-plugin-dialogs also provides similar implementations of `navigator.notification.confirm()` and `navigator.notification.prompt()`, each with completion callbacks.

There is an interesting bit of code in [`tests.js`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/7c2810e885e6269fdafb84d754786016ce2d1f82/tests/tests.js#L30) from cordova-plugin-inappbrowser:

```js
window.alert = window.alert || navigator.notification.alert;
if (isWindows && navigator && navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {
    // window.alert is defined but not functional on UWP
    window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
}
```

Note how this function sets `window.alert` to be the same as `navigator.notification.alert` on platforms where there is no `window.alert`, and also on UWP. While not directly related to your situation, this illustrates how there may be different implementations on different platforms. But using `navigator.notification.alert()` should let you write compatible code for all. Just don't assume anything about whether this function returns immediately or waits for the alert to be dismissed - use the `alertCallback` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael.  I understand it, but the problem I see then is that the webPage layer must take in account being embedded in the Cordova plugin what I think is against a proper layer design.

Comment: We realized about this `alert` management when debugging a similar error when using __doPostBack() from an Asp page. Even if Cordova-PlugIn has an implementation for `alert()` the problem with the __doPostBack would persist